# Add and update data to Solr-4.3.0 using node module solr-client

Tags: node.js, solr, solr4, node-modules

Let me take an example to explain the scenario. Suppose i have data indexed to Solr as :

```
{
 "id" : "872919092",
 "filename" : "science_book",
 "path" : "/local/abc/"
}
```

Now i want to modify the data already indexed to Solr with `id : 872919092`. I need to change the `filename : science_book` with `filename : history_book` and add new attribute `topic : mughal` to the same indexed data keeping `path` unchanged. I do not want to pass the `path` again as there is no change in that and already indexed to Solr. According to the documentation of [Solr](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages#Optional_attributes_for_.22field.22)
this is possible. How do i do that using nodejs solr-client [update](http://lbdremy.github.io/solr-node-client/code/solr.js.html) method? I want to achieve the below scene :

1. If the attribute does not exist in the Solr indexed data with particular id, add that to the already indexed data keeping the previously indexed data unchanged.
2. If the attribute already exists in the Solr indexed data with particular id, change the value of the previously indexed attribute keeping the other indexed data unchanged.

I am passing the data to add in Solr as a hash which is a combination of only the new attributes to be added to already indexed data in Solr and changes in the value of the previously indexed data to Solr.

**Note :** I am using **Solr-4.3.0** and node module **solr-client** for adding data to Solr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to add set or add to the field and remove the rest of the fields. You need id and the fields.

```
var doc = {
   "id" : "872919092",
   filename : {"set" : "history_book"},
   topic : {"add" : "mughal"}
}

client.add(doc)
```

Also note that you can increment or decrement int's using inc or dec

Comment: Just to add a point to your answer, "set" also adds the new field if previously the field does not exist in the Solr indexed data.

Comment: Hi, I have done the above code it works fine. But after adding that I have to manually commit. To remove this I have set ```autoCommit = true```. But still it is not working. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: you can use client.commit(). It even supports callbacks.