# node-solr-client: Updating Document and Commiting

Tags: node.js, solr, client, solr5

I am using node-solr-client for handling solr queries. I have written an update query as per the post here

[Add and update data to Solr-4.3.0 using node module solr-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17521159/add-and-update-data-to-solr-4-3-0-using-node-module-solr-client)

My data is:

```
data = {
    'type_s':'applicant',
    'id': 5,
    'state_id':{'set':565656},
};
```

I have enabled autocommit to true

```
client = solr.createClient();
client.autoCommit = true;
```

When I run the code it gives me a response

```
{ responseHeader: { status: 0, QTime: 4 } }
```

Meaning it has been added to the index. But when I crosscheck using solr admin, I don't see the updates. Now when I run http://localhost:8983/solr/jobs/update?commit=true and check again then it is visible in solr admin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I got it working.

I just had to add a softcommit(). Here is the code.

```
data = {
    'type_s':'applicant',
    'id': 5,
    'state_id':{'set':565656},
};

client = solr.createClient();

//client.autoCommit = true;

client.add(data, function(err, obj) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err.stack);
    } else {
      client.softCommit();
    }
  });
});
```

It just worked. I think the autoCommit option is not working or I am misconfiguring something.

Comment: Yep, I'd say the auoCommit option is either not working, or otherwise very mysterious.